# What is the best way to modify Claims at Relying Party when using Windows Identity Foundation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wif, claims-based-identity

Currently I am doing this to modify my Roles Claims in the Relying Party's Global.asax.

```
void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
 if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {

   string[] roleListArray = Roles.GetRolesForUser(User.Identity.Name);
   IClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User as IClaimsPrincipal;
   IClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = (IClaimsIdentity)claimsPrincipal.Identity;
   var roleclaims = claimsIdentity.Claims.FindAll(c => c.ClaimType == ClaimTypes.Role);
   foreach (Claim item in roleclaims)
   {
     claimsIdentity.Claims.Remove(item);
   }

   foreach(string role in roleListArray)
   {
     claimsIdentity.Claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
   }

   HttpContext.Current.User = claimsPrincipal;

  }
}
```

Is this the right way or is there a better way to modify a Claim in the Relying Party after successful authentication by STS?

Comment: did you tried using ***ClaimsAuthenticationManager*** ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the ClaimsAuthenticationManager.

Refer [ClaimsAuthenticationManager, ClaimsAuthorizationManager, and OriginalIssuer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748497.aspx)

Comment: So basically I moved my code from Authenticate in global.asax to Authenticate in the CustomModule. It works as the above code. What real difference or benefit I get by using it in ClaimsAuthenticationManager. One thing I see is better manageability since I have it in a separate library but that will be the case for even a regular HttpModule correct?